# Loading a datagrid with large amounts of data in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I am breaking up my project in small sections and one of the sections involves loading a grid with possibily lots of records (could be up to 1000s of records in the database).

Ideally I would like some sort of mechanism where as the users scrolls the grid, more data is retrieved.

I have read that certain controls (datapager with RIA) do this but I would like to know how I could implement this myself or do something similiar?

I was thinking about first loading 50 records at a time and when the user gets to scroll near the 50th record, then get another 50 as a start and so on. Not sure how I do this but this does not feel right or whether I should load ids of records in the grid and then get each row to load itself via an async thread but then I am hitting my database for each record?

Thanks

JD.

Comment: +1, that would be nice wouldn't it.  Paging is for techno-apologists.  A simple scroll-bar that causes a "data pager" to pre-fetch a page or two ahead would be a much nicer UI for the user who simply sees a large list.  I don't know of any grids that support this at present.

Comment: I beat my head against this for a couple of days, trying all sorts of combinations of IEnumerable<> with a 'yield return', etc.  I eventually loaded 10K records into a DataGrid and realized that it can handle that amount easily.  So I stopped looking for a solution for now, and simply implemented a class that loads all data in the background, loading new data when the search target changes.  But when I do start looking for a solution again, I think my best bet will be to implement ICollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are describing data virtulization. Xceed seems to be working on a commercial control with this capability but to date have not realeased anything(see [Xceed DataGrid for Silverlight Tech Preview!](http://xceed.com/CS/blogs/dontpanic/archive/2010/02/24/xceed-datagrid-for-silverlight-tech-preview.aspx) ). For some ideas from the WPF world on doing this you can check out:

- [Data virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344)
- [How can I improve on existing WPF data virtualization solutions?](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=378)

Comment: Thanks Dave. I was trying to avoid going down the 3rd party component route but before going there, I will look at the other links you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have just published a couple of articles with some sample code describing how to do stealth paging/data virtualization in silverlight without using any third-party components.

Read the [introductory post](http://blog.hibernatingrhinos.com/12513/data-virtualization-lazy-loading-stealth-pagingndash-whatever-you-want-to-call-it-herersquo-s-how-to-do-it-in-silverlight) to find out about [the sample](https://github.com/samueldjack/VirtualCollection), and then follow up with [Digging into VirtualCollection](http://blog.hibernatingrhinos.com/12514/data-virtualization-in-silverlight-digging-into-virtualcollection).